# WSO2 IS: SCIM API Update: Required attribute userName is missing in the SCIM Object

Tags: wso2, scim

How to update user with PATCH, why it require userName (with PUT is the same)?

```
curl -v -k --admin:admin -X PATCH -d '{"name":{"familyName":"Doe"}' \
--header "Content-Type:application/json" \
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/bd61878b-a37c-4c71-ab76-c553d559539f

Required attribute userName is missing in the SCIM Object
```

I have secondary user store with immutable userName. When I try to enter userName also in param the same not changed. It reports me:

```
User name is immutable in carbon user store.
```

I am using wso2 is 5.1. Is there any way to update user using SCIM API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try as mentioned in [here](http://tanyamadurapperuma.blogspot.com/2013/10/tricky-way-to-modify-username-scim.html).